Desarrollando en Android Studio, la aplicación se detiene al ir a una pantalla
Estoy desarrollando en Android Studio y por alguna razón la aplicación se detiene al ir a una pantalla. ¿Qué puedo hacer?
Acá está el código de la actividad a la que quiero acceder en Java:
package com.example.as;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class practica extends AppCompatActivity {  
//Aca esta   
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_practica);
        String actividadAnterior = getIntent().getStringExtra("actividad_anterior");

        TextView text = findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        Cuerdas hola = new Cuerdas();
        double[][] cuerdas = hola.getCuerdas();
        boolean[][] tabs = new boolean[0][0];
        int segprac = 0;

        boolean[][] finalTabs = tabs;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i >= 6; i++){
                    for (int o = 0; o >= 12; o++){
                        if (finalTabs[i][o]){
                            text.setText(getString((int) cuerdas[i][o]));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finish();
            }
        }, segprac);



        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {`          
    Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
                v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 
systemBars.bottom);
                return insets;
           });
        }
    }


Se detiene? Quieres decir que crashea? Incluye el error en tu pregunta. Puedes obtenerlo usando logcat.

Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el recorrido y leer ¿cómo preguntar?. Nos vendría bien conocer el contenido de la excepción que está cerrando tu aplicación. En ella se te está indicando el motivo y, probablemente, el número de línea del código que genera el problema.


Tienes un error de declaración en el bucle for siendo i < 6 y o < 12), dependiendo de las dimensiones de tus arrays.
tabs lo tienes mal inicializado se ha inicializado como un array vacío.
segprac debería ser mayor que 0 si no quieres que no se ejecute inmediatamente.
En text.setText(getString((int) cuerdas[i][o])) si cuerdas es double necesitarás convertirlo a cadena.

